# Colorbox in IE8 on XP not loading

Tags: internet-explorer-8, windows-xp, colorbox

I have Colorbox and SuberBGImage on one page and when testing my page in Internet Explorer 8 on Windows XP the image deosn't pop up and I get the following message: Invalid argument jquery-1.3.2.min.js Line 12 Code: 0 Char: 12949

Here is a link to the page: http://j-works.de/bathroomsint/02_showroom/index.htm

Here is my code in the hope that someone can locate the error:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../60_scripts/SuperBGImage/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../60_scripts/SuperBGImage/jquery.effects.core.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../60_scripts/SuperBGImage/jquery.effects.slide.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../60_scripts/SuperBGImage/jquery.effects.blind.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../60_scripts/SuperBGImage/jquery.superbgimage.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    $(function() {

// Options for SuperBGImage
$.fn.superbgimage.options = {
    randomtransition: 2, // 0-none, 1-use random transition (0-7)
    slideshow: 0, // 0-none, 1-autostart slideshow
    slide_interval: 10000, // interval for the slideshow
    randomimage: 1, // 0-none, 1-random image
    speed: 2000 // animation speed
};

// initialize SuperBGImage
$('#thumbs').superbgimage().hide();

    });

    function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
      var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
        var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
        if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
    }

    function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
      var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
    }

    function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
      var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
        d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
      if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
      for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
      if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
    }

    function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
  var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments; document.MM_sr=new Array; for(i=0;i<(a.length-2);i+=3)
       if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){document.MM_sr[j++]=x; if(!x.oSrc) x.oSrc=x.src; x.src=a[i+2];}
    }

    function MM_showHideLayers() { //v6.0
      var i,p,v,obj,args=MM_showHideLayers.arguments;
      for (i=0; i<(args.length-2); i+=3) if ((obj=MM_findObj(args[i]))!=null) { v=args[i+2];
if (obj.style) { obj=obj.style; v=(v=='show')?'visible':(v=='hide')?'hidden':v; }
        obj.visibility=v; }
    }
    //-->
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../60_Scripts/colorbox/colorbox.css" />
    <script src="../60_Scripts/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
    <script src="../60_Scripts/colorbox/colorbox.js"></script>
    </head>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does ColorBox does not appear in Internet Explorer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416300/why-does-colorbox-does-not-appear-in-internet-explorer)